# how to show login/logout toplink in order tracking page in magento

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

In every page,login/ logout toplinks is showing but in order tracking page,login/logout link is not visible. I tried to find the problem but i didnot get the solution.I want to show login toplink in order tracking page also.
If anybody knows this,Please help me out.
Thanks!

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position/></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>

<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position/></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the login/logout link via xml (local.xml).

Use following code and change it for your needs:

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="reference_block_on_order_tracking_page">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position/></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>

<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="reference_block_on_order_tracking_page">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position/></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Comment: I created local .xml page in app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/local.xml and put the above code,then also it is not coming. i cleared the cache also

Comment: change reference name

Comment: I tried to put this code in customer.xml also,then also it is not working

Comment: give me some idea to solve this why it is not working

Comment: I used reference name "reference_block_on_order_tracking_page". Did you change this to the block you want to add the links to?

Comment: I want to add in toplinks so i have written the code like that please see above

Comment: i want one login/logout link in ordertracking page so i am not getting what i will write in reference name.please explain it. please see my above code and tell me where i am comitting mistake